# How To Calling a Stored Procedure in Worklight

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I have just started working on IBM Worklight. I  ran a SQL Adapter , in which it uses the procedure to fetch data from database and displays in JSON format.But I want to use that stored procedure in my HTML file regarding to display records in my frontend UI. please provide me any suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have written and tested your adapter you can invoke the adapter from an application using this syntax:

```
function getData() {
var invocationData = {
        adapter : 'ADAPTER_NAME',
        procedure : 'PROCEDURE_NAME',
        parameters : []
    };

WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,{
    onSuccess : getDataSuccess,
    onFailure : getDataFailure,
});
}
```

OnSuccess (when the data is returned to the application) calls (in this example) a function called getDataSuccess. This function will receive the JSON data returned from the Worklight server.

onFailure calls (in this example) a function called getDataFailure that will receive the error sent from the Worklight server.

For more information check [module 6 - Invoking Adapter Procedures from the Client Applications (PDF, 370KB)](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/Module_06_-_Invoking_Adapter_Procedures_from_the_Client_Applications.pdf) and [the exercise and code sample (ZIP, 53.7KB)](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/module_06_0_EngadgetReader.zip)