# How to display data in worklight using SQL adapter

Tags: sql, authentication, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

When a user enters the login and password I can not display his profile (information from the database) in the next page, I used SQL Adapter to ensure the connection with the database, but until now the only thing that I can do is to visualize the information using an "alert" in JavaScript not in the page that follows the page of authentication.

I'm using Dojo if it is necessary to mention.

Comment: Provide code samples of what you're doing.

Comment: See my edited answer below.

Answer (score 0):

As you did not ask anything technical, I will point you to the Getting Started material. Familiarize yourself with Worklight adapters and authentication concepts (also look at the sample applications). If you then have a technical question, ask.

1. [Worklight Adapters](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#server-side-development)
2. [Authentication in Worklight](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#security)

To display data retrieved via a SQL adapter, see this question (it does not implement authentication, you'll need to combine the two on your own): [How to use adapter inside the application in worklight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646797/how-to-use-adapter-inside-the-application-in-worklight)