# displaying worklight sql adapter resultSet dojo datagrid

Tags: datagrid, dojo, adapter, ibm-mobilefirst

I am new to both worklight adapters and dojo

I am using a SQL Adapter to return JSON format resultSet from a table, which I would like to display in a dojo datagrid.

How do I do this ?

Could anyone please point me to code samples ?

Comment: Hi @user2397334, if the answer below allows you to display the results, can you please mark as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a SQL Adapter using the Worklight adapter wizard.  Please see exercise and code sample "SQL adapter – Communicating with SQL database" on developerWorks for a full walk through: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html.
2. Next invoke the adapter using:

   WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,{
      onSuccess : getDataSuccess,
      onFailure : getDataFailure,
   });

   Please see: [How to use adapter inside the application in worklight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646797/how-to-use-adapter-inside-the-application-in-worklight)
3. On successful retrieval of your data you can then populate a dojo data store and use   it as the store in your dojox.grid.DataGrid.

   Please see: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html