# Database connection to IBM Worklight for android application development

Tags: android, mysql, database, ibm-mobilefirst

I am working for android application development and i need database connection there in support of my app. Please suggest me a useful solution for the connection of the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the backend calls ( including DB or any other web services ) are handled by Adapters in Worklight. I would suggest to go through this [link](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fdevref%2Fc_overview_of_ibm_worklight_adap.html)  to know more about Adapters.

and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646797/how-to-use-adapter-inside-the-application-in-worklight) for more examples.

For connecting Database you should use SQL adapters.